# How to make a object support deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I get the InvalidOperationException when I try to deserialize a json string for my person object. It states that my Person object is not supported for deserialization

```
  [DataContract]
  public class Person
  {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
  }
```

An example of the json string

```
[{"name":"FirstName","value":"John"},{"name":"LastName","value":"Doe"},{"name":"Id","value":"1001"}]
```

And here's where I get my exception

```
  Person p = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(json);
```

I've tried the DataContractJsonSerializer too without much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code and found the problem.

Your jSon string provided a array of `Person`. Change to `Person[]` and it will work.

Here is my test code

```
string json = "[{\"name\":\"FirstName\",\"value\":\"John\"},{\"name\":\"LastName\",\"value\":\"Doe\"},{\"name\":\"Id\",\"value\":\"1001\"}]";
Person[] p = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
```

### Update

Your jSon string is not in the right format. The Deserializer cant find the property to assign your values.

The right would be.

```
{ "NameOfProperty" : "ValueOfProperty" }
```

This is a right format

```
[{"FirstName":"Jon", "LastName":"Doe"}, {"FirstName":"Jon", "LastName":"Doe"}]
```

**Test Code**

```
string json = "[{\"FirstName\":\"Jon\", \"LastName\":\"Doe\"}, {\"FirstName\":\"Jon\", \"LastName\":\"Doe\"}]";
Person[] p = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
```

Comment: I get an array of three persons, but none of them have valid values. The json string provided should result in the array having only one person.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll look into how the string is generated :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the json string is an *array* of Persons (people?!?), not a single `Person`.

Change your deserialization to

```
Person[] p = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
```

and it'll work.

**[Edit - in response to your comment]**
Yes - this will give three Person instances, - and, in fact, they'll all have null/zero properties.

I suspect you really were expecting what *this* json string would give you with your original code:

```
string json = "[{\"FirstName\":\"John\", \"LastName\":\"Doe\",\"Id\":\"1001\"}]";
```

which is a single person, John Doe, with an id of 1001. But this is not what the json says if deserialised into a `Person`.

What you original json *can* be deserialized into is an array of name/value pairs like this:

```
public class NameValuePair
{
    public string name;
    public string value;
}
```

using this

```
var p = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<NameValuePair[]>(json);
```

Hopefully this snippet illustrates the relationship between the json and the class a bit better.

Comment: Thanks, that made it run with no exception, but I get returned an array of three persons, not one person with the values from the json string